# Connect from WAN while OpenVPN Client connection is active

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, openvpn, local-area-network

I've been trying to get this working for a while now, but still unsuccessfully. I hope you will be able to help me with it.

I've got machine (Raspberry Pi), which has:

- Static local IP: 192.168.1.131 (eth0)
- OpenVPN server running in subnet 192.168.2.X (tun0)
- Raspberry connects via eth0 to the router (192.168.1.1) which has some ports forwarded to Raspberry's IP - I can connect to my services from WAN using external IP address given by my ISP

So far so good, everything works as expected. My config is following:
Once tun0 is established I apply following iptable rules:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

and routing table looks like:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     192.168.2.2     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.2.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

Now I would like to add OpenVPN client and setup it as default internet connection for system.
Once connection is established (tun1) new routing is being applied by VPN service provider,
but I'm loosing possibility to connect to my services from WAN using my external IP.

In this situation routing look like that:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.159.0.145    128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.159.0.1      10.159.0.145    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun1
10.159.0.145    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
45.86.203.67    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.159.0.145    128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     192.168.2.2     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.2.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

(IP that I'm getting from VPN Provider is dynamic)

As I understand it's because my server now sends responses via tun1, instead of eth0.
I've read about Policy Based Routing, but still cannot get it work properly. I managed to route all network incoming from 192.168.1.1 (the router), and connection from WAN started to wor, but in this situation I cannot connect from other machines in LAN.

Thank you in advance for any tips how to properly solve this.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I isolated my problem to having just 2 WAN active connections, then after digging a little bit I managed to made it working. Once VPN established connection I call:

```
echo 200 WAN >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

ip rule add from 192.168.1.131 table WAN priority 900
ip rule add iif eth0 table WAN priority 1000

ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table WAN
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto static scope link src 192.168.1.131 table WAN
```

Now my default gateway is TUN1 (Commercial VPN), but I still can connect using my external IP or from other machines in the same lan 192.168.1.0/24.

Last remaining problem I noticed is now I cannot connect to my VPN server (TUN0) that I'm hosting on port 1194 UDP.

All other services using TCP are accesible, only those using UDP not - what I missed here?